# My modal is automatically coming as this page is opening

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

On clicking button it is coming well.
But problem is that as the page opens it comes up automatically, whereas i want that only on button click this should happen.
    
    
     test modal

```
    <div class="col-md-2"><center/><button class="btn btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">TIME ZONE</button> </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Time Zone            </h4> 
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-body">
                Add some text here      
                </div>   
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    <script>    $(function () { $('#myModal').modal({       keyboard: true    })}); </script>


    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you tell me the line of click event which i should write, please.
I have tried several ways but its not happening only on button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
<input type="button" id="btn"/>

$(function () { 
    $("#btn").click(function(){
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });

});
```